# How to change port on simplehttpserver in linux?

Tags: linux, http, python, tcp

How to change port from 8000 on simplehttpserver in linux?

Comment: Please tell me you at least *tried* a cursory google search before posting this question?

Comment: @EEAA My google search took me here!

Answer (score 18):

The following was found in the **first** result for a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=simplehttpserver) for "simplehttpserver".

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer <port_number>
```

Comment: And now the first google result for "simplehttpserver change port" is this page

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to know about this but realized that I was using the `simplehttpserver` package installed from `npm` (though internally it still uses the python version). I found out a bit more about the package here: https://github.com/tikonen/blog/tree/master/simplehttpserver. Although not mentioned in the docs, a quick read-through of the code points to the answer.

Here is what I found: `simplehttpserver <-b bindhost> <-p port> <-m mimetype> <webroot>`